# Brackets In javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project where you can insert a link.
You can enter the link url and text. I used prompt to collect that information.
I coded this:

```
document.getElementById(ev.target.id).innerHTML = y + "<a href=" + linkurl + " > + linktext + </a>";
```

When I use the code, The link appears as: `+ linktext +` .

Can I make the link text say the text that I prompted?

Comment: You don't need `getElementById()` - the value of `ev.target` is already the DOM element, so you don't need to get it again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a variable, don't put it inside a string literal. Include quotes around *each* piece of the literal string.

```
document.getElementById(ev.target.id).innerHTML = y + "<a href=" + linkurl + " > " + linktext + " </a>";
```

That said, piecing together HTML by mashing together strings can lead to rather confusing code, as you've discovered. Try using DOM methods instead.

```
var element = ev.target;
element.innerHTML = ""; // Erase existing content
element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(y));
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = linkurl;
link.appendChild(document.createTexTNode(linktext));
element.appendChild(link);
```

It is more verbose, but less error prone.

Answer (score 1):

You missed double quote `" + linktext + "`

```
document.getElementById(ev.target.id).innerHTML = y + "<a href=" + linkurl + " > " + linktext + " </a>";
```

Comment: Actually, I find another error here. Should be `"<a href=\"" + linkurl + "\" > " + linktext + " </a>";`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById(ev.target.id).innerHTML = y + "" + linktext;
```